# Body on Mobile moving around

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I am having issues with SOME of the Pages on phone view. It seems like the body is moving side to side. There is no scroll bar but you can move it around with your finger. The Home Page, and some other Pages are not currently doing this.

I'm using Elementor, over OnePress Thema.

I tried with:

```
html,
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

but then blocks some other block-elements :(

Ive had this issue for a while and never found a solution.

Best regards and thank you!

Comment: You can try with `!important` property like `html,body {overflow-x: hidden !important;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find elements which are doing this issue. My way to find buggy DOM is deleting "containers" one by one and check if x-axis scrolling is still possible.

When you find these elements you should try edit their styles.

For example boxes with padding and percentage width can do it, if they doesnt have `box-sizing: border-box` property

Comment: Great! It works the way you recommend it to me. Thanky you, Veter!